# How to unpivot columns dynamically using SQL server 2014

Tags: sql-server, unpivot

Data in SQL table is

```
Cust_Name   Prd_Name    1/1/2019    2/1/2019    3/1/2019
John        Mobile        18.5        45.7       66.9
Scott       Laptop         9.5        3.7         0
```

I want to unpivot columns [1/1/2019], [2/1/2019], [3/1/2019] and want the result as below

```
Cust_Name   Prd_Name     Sales_Month    Value
John        Mobile        1/1/2019      18.5
John        Mobile        2/1/2019      45.7
John        Mobile        3/1/2019      66.9
Scott       Laptop        1/1/2019      9.5
Scott       Laptop        2/1/2019      3.7
Scott       Laptop        3/1/2019      0
```

How can I do this ? Also number of such columns which I want to unpivot is dynamic so it starts with 1/1/2019 , 2/1/2019 but it can proceed till 12/1/2019

Comment: Going to ask the same question here I asked on another website: Does this need to be dynamic? Are you adding new columns to your table each month (so next month you'll have a column 04/01/2019)? If so, I'd suggest that what you need to do isn't create a dynamic pivot, you need to fix your database design so that it's like the data in your second dataset. Or is that your aim of this? (But then like I said, there's no need for dynamic SQL.)

Comment: Yes, a new column will be added like 4/1/2019, 5/1/2019...
And cannot change database design as this is how I get data, so I want to create SQL query (dynamic is one approach that I see) which will handle this and create data like the expected second dataset.

Comment: Ouch that is just painful. You will have to use sys.columns to help you build dynamic sql to do this because you don't know how many columns you have.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an option that will dynamically unpivot your data without actually using dynamic SQL.

**XML does not like item names beginning with numbers**, so we have to do a little clean-up... thus the `replace(replace(replace(...)))`

**Example**

```
Select A.Cust_Name
      ,A.Prd_Name
      ,Sales_Month = replace(
                     replace(
                     replace(C.Item,'_x003','')
                     ,'__x002F_','/')
                     ,'_x002F_','/')
      ,C.Value 
 From  YourTable A
 Cross Apply ( values (cast((Select A.* for XML RAW) as xml))) B(XMLData)
 Cross Apply (
                Select Item  = xAttr.value('local-name(.)', 'varchar(100)')
                      ,Value = xAttr.value('.','varchar(max)')
                 From  XMLData.nodes('//@*') xNode(xAttr)
                 Where xAttr.value('local-name(.)','varchar(100)') not in ('Cust_Name','Prd_Name')
             ) C
```

**Returns**

```
Cust_Name   Prd_Name    Sales_Month Value
John        Mobile      1/1/2019    18.5
John        Mobile      2/1/2019    45.7
John        Mobile      3/1/2019    66.9
Scott       Laptop      1/1/2019    9.5
Scott       Laptop      2/1/2019    3.7
Scott       Laptop      3/1/2019    0.0
```